# Make logo appear to "hang off" nav with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, nav

What am i trying to achieve is something like this:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/109053092/Screen%20Shot%202015-01-21%20at%2014.49.45.png

I am using Bootstrap 3 and I am using the code below to create my nav:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
 <a href="index.php" title="Barcelona 226 Center Exclusive - Official site"><img src="../assets/images/logo.png" alt="Barcelona226"></a>
</div>
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="apartments" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Exclusive Apartments <span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
<li><a href="../apartments">View All</a></li>
<li class="dropdown-header">4 Bedroom</li>
<li><a href="#">Superior</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Standard</a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li class="dropdown-header">3 Bedroom</li>
<li><a href="#">Superior</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Superior Tuset</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="active"><a href="../rooms">Exclusive Rooms</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Contact and Location</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
```

I cant figure out how, any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply try with this CSS for your logo element :

```
position : absolute;
top : 10px;
```

Absolute position will take the element out its container.

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/puhjdjng/)

Comment: Now i have this problem https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/109053092/Screen%20Shot%202015-01-22%20at%2011.36.31.png How can i make the logo go to the back when the menu is open?

Comment: Do you mean hide the logo ?

Comment: You can use the next browser element selector. See my [feedle](http://jsfiddle.net/puhjdjng/1/)

Comment: Perfect! One small thing when the menu is closing the border overlaps the logo for a brief second,https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/109053092/Screen%20Shot%202015-01-23%20at%2009.09.25.png can i stop this? Not major just a minor annoyance

Comment: It's because of the animation, and you can't remove it : a solution with some lines of JS [here](http://jsfiddle.net/puhjdjng/2/)